# How to get a specific value from a user-input list and multiply it with another value

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, math

```
# creating an empty list
game_titles = []
game_prices = []
 
# number of elements as input
n = int(input("Enter number of game titles (followed by ENTER on the keyboard): "))

# iterating till the range
print('Enter the name of each game (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):')
for i in range(0, n):
    input_names = input()
    # adding the element
    game_titles.append(input_names) 
    
print('Enter the price of each game (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):')
for i in range(0, n):
    input_prices = input('$')
    game_prices.append(input_prices) 
    
print('\nGAMES IN STOCK')
list_of_lists = [game_titles, game_prices]
 # make a list of lists
 
# to print list vertically
for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    for x in list_of_lists:
        print(x[i], end =' ')
    print()
    
while True:
    try:
        game_to_purchase = str(input("Please enter the name of the game you would like to purchase: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, that game is not in stock. Please enter a game that is in stock:")
        continue

    if game_to_purchase not in game_titles:
        print("Sorry, that game is not in stock.\n")
        continue
    else:
        break
        #age was successfully parsed, and we're happy with its value.
        #we're ready to exit the loop.

while True:
    try:
        num_copies = int(input("Please enter the number of copies you would like to purchase (1-10): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, that was an invalid input. Please try again.")
        continue

    if num_copies > 10:
        print("Sorry, there aren't enough copies. Please enter a number lower than 10.\n")
        continue
    else:
        break
    
total_price = (num_copies * ___)    
print('The total for', num_copies, 'of', game_to_purchase, 'is', total_price)
```

Hi there, I am trying to have the user input two lists, one with video game names and another with the prices. At the end of the loop, I need to get take the number of copies the user would like to input and multiply it with the price of a single game to get the total price for the purchase. Problem is, I'm really not sure how to do that and I've been struggling for hours. Can someone recommend how to do this? Please see the second to last line. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the flow of your program a bit. Instead of getting all titles then prices, I ask for the title and price for each game in order and store it in a list of dicts. I also added quantity so you don't have to hard code the limit of 10. Minor thing but you don't need str(input()) because it is already always a string. There is still a ton you can improve here this is just a start.

```
# creating an empty list
games = []

# number of elements as input
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter number of game titles (followed by ENTER on the keyboard): "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number.")
        continue

# iterating till the range
for i in range(1, n+1):
    while True:
        try:
            print(f'Enter the name game#{i} (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):')
            title = input()
            print(f'Enter the price game#{i} (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):')
            price = float(input())
            print(f'Enter the quantity available for game#{i} (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):')
            quantity = int(input())
            games.append({
                'title': title,
                'price': price,
                'quantity': quantity,
            })
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input. Try again.')
            continue

print('\nGAMES IN STOCK')
# to print list vertically
print('{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format('TITLE', 'PRICE', 'IN-STOCK QTY'))
for d in games:
    print('{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(d['title'], d['price'], d['quantity']))

while True:
    game_to_purchase = input("Please enter the name of the game you would like to purchase: ")

    if game_to_purchase not in [g['title'] for g in games]:
        print("Game not found. Try again.\n")
        continue
    else:
        price = [g['price'] for g in games if g['title'] == game_to_purchase][0]
        copies_available = int([g['quantity'] for g in games if g['title'] == game_to_purchase][0])
        break

while True:
    try:
        num_copies = int(input("Please enter the number of copies you would like to purchase: "))
        if num_copies > copies_available:
            print(f"Sorry, there aren't enough copies. Please enter a number lower than {copies_available}.\n")
            continue
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, that was an invalid input. Please try again.")
        continue

total_price = num_copies * price
print(f'The total for {num_copies} of {game_to_purchase} is ${total_price}')
```

---

Output:

```
Enter number of game titles (followed by ENTER on the keyboard): 2
Enter the name game#1 (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):
game1
Enter the price game#1 (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):
10
Enter the quantity available for game#1 (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):
5
Enter the name game#2 (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):
game2
Enter the price game#2 (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):
20
Enter the quantity available for game#2 (followed by ENTER on the keyboard):
3

GAMES IN STOCK
TITLE      PRICE      IN-STOCK QTY
game1      10.0       5         
game2      20.0       3         
Please enter the name of the game you would like to purchase: game2
Please enter the number of copies you would like to purchase: 2
The total for 2 of game2 is $40.0
```

Comment: I get an invalid input when I run your code.

Comment: What are you inputting? I will edit my answer to show example output.

Comment: I miss-inputted. This works great, thanks!